# Getting "Max Request Length Exceeded Error" in SSRS/BI report

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I have seen on Stackoverflow where people have had problems deploying reports on Power BI, but this time I am having problems running a particular report.

I get an error banner when I view the report, after I hit the View Report button:

[image]
PageRequestManagementException (status code is 500)

When I go to the server logs, it gives me this error

library!ReportServer_0-89!8edc!09/01/2020-15:23:22:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeException: The request has been aborted., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeException: An error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportServer_PBIRS_0-89-132434232852147709. Most likely, the HTTP request contains an unsupported verb or invalid syntax. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.

I would understand if I were trying to deploy this report but I'm trying to run it, and it doesn't matter what date I use to filter the report.

Now, in order to understand this further, I looked at the .rdl file to see how big it was.  It's 255KB in size.  I also exported the data to an excel spreadsheet from Report Builder, where I was able to run the report successfully (not an option for our endusers, just FYI).  The Excel sheet is 1.31MB.

I know I'm missing something, and I know editing the web.config file will alleviate this problem but what do I set it to?  I can't figure out what size I need, and I really want to make sure I don't overdo it and set us up for a DOS attack.

Answer (score 0):

Our system admin doubled the maxrequestlength parameter in the web.config and it seems like this has alleviated the problem,